# how to see and show where this sequence converges to

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a question from NBHM-2022. the question is

"Let $f(x)$ be the function on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x):= \sin(\pi x/2)$. For $y \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the sequence $\{x_n(y)\}$ defined by
$$x_0(y):= y, x_{n+1}(y)=f(x_n(y)), \forall n \geq 1,$$
and let $g(y):= \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n(y).$ Find $\int_0^3 g(y)dy$.

I tried to construct the sequence in general in which I failed...
then I tried to see whether I can do with something to do with uniform convergence, for that also I need to find the limit of the sequence so that we will get g(y) explicitly.  Kindly help me how to solve

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that the dynamical system defined by iterating $f$ has three fixed points, $\{-1,0,1\}$. Show that $\{-1,1\}$ are attracting, and deduce the pointwise limit $g: [0,3] \rightarrow [-1,1]$.

Comment: Bro I have a doubt, what is the major paper associated with this question, To understand about the subject where can I refer and what is the subject for instance...